# Data binding a WPF ComboBox from a ViewModel - can't change selected item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'll get this out of the way right off the bat... my base view model class is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Here's the scenario:

I have a single view with a single view model. The view is a master/detail with the master being a list box of `Game` objects that I'm populating without issue. When a `Game` object is selected in the master list box, I want to populate some details in various controls. The control that's causing me problems is a combo box.

Now, the `combobox` is being populated using a collection of `Team` objects. Each `Game` object has a "Team" object and once the `combobox` is populated, I want to select the appropriate `Team` object in the `combobox` that the `Game` object specifies.

Now, I know this is working to some degree because if I do the same binding to a `textbox`, the right information appears (I can get the bound `Team` object to appear in the `textbox`, but I can't get it to select from the list).

I'm seriously lost, been working on this for a few hours now. Can anyone assist?

Edit: I have a feeling this has something to do with the object references. But wouldn't `SelectedValue` still work?

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel:

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams
    {
        get { return this.teams; }
        set
        {
            this.teams = value;
            OnPorpertyChanged("Teams");
        }
    }

    public Team SelectedTeam
    {
        get { return this.selectedTeam; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedTeam = value;
            OnPorpertyChanged("SelectedTeam");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Team> teams;
    private Team selectedTeam;
```

Team Class:

```cs
    public class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

View:

```
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource, Path=SelectedTeam}" />
```

Comment: The example above is what I currently have and it doesn't work. The problem is that when the view loads, the view model already has a team assigned to the selected team, and the selected team isn't appearing in the combo box when it loads. What can I do?

When I select a team from the combo box, the new team value IS applied to the view model, but it won't load the existing selected value when the view loads.

Comment: I should say that the selected team isn't SELECTED in the combo box (the combo box has no visible item selected on the interface, it's blank, but the object it is bound to does have a value)

Comment: @Basti, did you get it to work eventually? I'm having a similar situation. Thanks.

Comment: When the ComobBox loads it is doing a reference match, not an equality match to find the exact instance of Team in the Teams collection. The problem you may be facing is that the instance of Team that is assigned to SelectedItem is not an instance of Team that exists in your Teams collection. You'll either need some code in your View or ViewModel that matches them up, or you'll need to bind to a unique Team property (like ID) so the ComboBox can perform the proper lookup.